# how to insert group checkbox values with PHP?

Tags: php, forms

PHP code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_details (check_box)
VALUES ('$_POST[check_box]')";
```

Below is my html code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" value="1"> Group 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" value="2"> Group 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box[]" value="3"> Group 3<br>
```

Comment: `"INSERT INTO user_details (check_box) VALUES (".implode('),(','$_POST[check_box]').");`

Comment: That solution above might work splendidly; but it doesn't account for parameterized queries - which you **really should use**.

Comment: @Qirel i know :-(

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions But since we don't see any relevant PHP code, we don't know which API is being used, so we can't really advise any more than what we already did ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in this way:

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO user_details (check_box) VALUES ("
        . implode('), (',$_POST[check_box])
        . ")";
```

this is open to mysql injections!! Better do

`$clean = array_map('intval',$_POST[check_box]);`

before using it.